# Using HTML entities in HTML attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm getting this:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [data-id=1|31|2]
```

So what I gather from this and my attempts to fix it is that you can't use any special characters in HTML attributes. So, does anyone know of a way I can separate numbers within an attribute and maintain the ability to manipulate with javascript?

I threw this together real quick to show the issue better than I can explain. http://jsfiddle.net/zacharynicoll/fbJYq/

Comment: Any reason why you chose not to enclose the expression in double quotes?

Comment: Reason? More like the absence of reason is why I chose to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not with the `|` symbol but with your selector.

```
$('ul[data-id=' + id + ']').show();
```

Should be

```
$('ul[data-id="' + id + '"]').show();
```

Without the quotes any special characters will be picked up as part of the selector.

Comment: Don't you hate when you work on a bug for an hour or so, and the solution turns out to be, "add this one little character." Thank you good sir, worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add the *double quotes*

From:

```
$('ul[data-id=' + id + ']').show();
```

To:

```
$('ul[data-id="' + id + '"]').show();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kgMGB/3/

Comment: Sorry Xander, you're absolutely correct, I did forget to add the double quotes, but Kokos answered first. Thanks though!

Answer (score 1):

Try with "":

```
 $('ul[data-id="' + id + '"]').show();
```

**EDIT: Wow, three people with the correct answer simultaneously. I won't delete mine though, but only because I think this is very funny :) ;) ;-) :)**
(Give the upvotes to the guy who was 1 min. faster, i.e the farthest down, I suggest)

Comment: To be fair, my answer works too and I was a minute quicker ;P

Comment: See my edit.... your immediately voiced worries make this even funnier, on this "free work for absolutely nothing" website - a great place for psychological studies :) ;) No offense, really, PLEASE.

Comment: Though mine works I've no idea whether it should work or not. But it does on my browser without the extra quotes.

Comment: You're a gentleman sir. The fact that three other people suggested it was the missing quotes leads me to believe they're more right than me but as I say, it works!

Comment: Meh, yours was one minute later than theirs, I wouldn't quite say simultaneously. :)

Comment: We were working on it at the same time. This is where nitpicking starts, time to leave.

Comment: For the record, I was in no way offended, I was merely being silly, I don't mind where the votes go.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the `|` with a `-`

http://jsfiddle.net/kgMGB/2/